# UINavigationBar shadow image is discarded when UISearchBar is used

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar

I need customized `UINavigationBar` appearance in my application. I use `UINavigationBar.appearance()` for that. I use custom shadow image (it replaces 1pt hairline in the bottom of the navigation bar):

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage(named: "navigationBarShadow")
```

So far so good. Customized navigation bar looks like this:

[image]

**The problem:**

Shadow image is discarded when I set navigation item search controller:

```
navigationItem.searchController = searchController
```

[image]

Notice, the hairline is back.

As soon as I comment previous code out, the appearance is back to expected:

[image]

**The question:** Is there a legal way to remove the hairline when `UISearchBar` is used along with custom appearance `UINavigaytionBar`?

**XCode 10** **iOS 11/12** solution would be enough.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks